# Create a new class instance with arguments stored in a list in Python

Tags: python, python-class

I'm wondering if there is a way to use an argument list for class initialization in Python.

For example in this class:

```py
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.result = a + b + c

t = TestClass(1, 2, 3)
print(t.result)
# 6
```

I use arguments a, b, c. If I have those arguments stored in list `l = [1, 2, 3]`, can I somehow apply `TestClass()` constructor to this list?

I'm looking for something similar as an [`apply`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm) function in Common Lisp, that would work with Python class constructors.

Comment: Did you try *l as single argument when creating the instance? Not saying this is robust code, but the option is there.

Comment: @Dilettant Thank you, it works. I had no idea something like this exists in Python.